# Dynamic pointer cast compile error when I compile with C++11

Tags: c++11, codeblocks, openframeworks

I'm developping an app with OpenFrameworks with C++ language.
In my program there is a line that makes a dynamic cast pointer

```
Ref_<ImageUniform> p = o.cast<ImageUniform>();
```

Here is the class that implementing the cast() function implementation

```
template <typename T>
struct Ref_ : public ofPtr<T>
{
    Ref_() {}
    Ref_(T *t) : ofPtr<T>(t) {}
    Ref_(const Ref_<T>& o) : ofPtr<T>(o) {}
    Ref_(const ofPtr<T>& o) : ofPtr<T>(o) {}

    template <typename TT>
    Ref_<TT> cast() const { return dynamic_pointer_cast<TT>(*this); }
};
```

When I compile without the -std=c++11 it works.
But when I put the -std=c++11 it prints me a compile error and refers me to an internal file "ofTypes.h" of the library of OpenFrameworks at this line 191:

```
#else
    template<typename Tp1>
    ofPtr(const ofPtr<Tp1>& __r, std::__dynamic_cast_tag)
    : std::shared_ptr<T>(__r, std::__dynamic_cast_tag()) { }
#endif
```

And also here is the compile error

> ......\libs\openFrameworks\types\ofTypes.h|193|error: no matching function >for call to 'std::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(const >ofPtr&, std::tr1::__dynamic_cast_tag)'|
>       #else
>           template
>           ofPtr(const ofPtr& __r, std::__dynamic_cast_tag)
>           : std::shared_ptr(__r, std::__dynamic_cast_tag()) { }
>       #endif

Answer (score 1):

Either you should update your version of OpenFrameworks (which supports C++11), or you should not compile current code with C++11.

Now you have problem with below code

```
   template<typename Tp1>
   ofPtr(const ofPtr<Tp1>& __r, std::__dynamic_cast_tag)
   : std::shared_ptr<T>(__r, std::__dynamic_cast_tag()) { }
```

when you compile this code without C++11, implementation of `shared_ptr` is taken from `tr1/memory` header. The code can be compiled because there is version of `shared_ptr` ctor which takes as second parameter `__dynamic_cast_tag`. When you try to compile the code with C++11, you will get error because `shared_ptr` implementation is taken from `memory` header (where there is no ctor of shared_ptr which takes `__dynamic_cast_tag` as second parameter).

Comment: Implementations of `shared_ptr` differ in `tr1/memory` (before C++) and `memory` (C++11) headers. Calling this line`std::shared_ptr<T>(__r, std::__dynamic_cast_tag())`  we want to use `shared_ptr` from C++11 not TR1, but in C++11 there is no `shared_ptr` in version where the second argument is `dynamic_cast_tag`, this is bug in header code https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/0.8.4/libs/openFrameworks/types/ofTypes.h .

Comment: This is what I noticed, so I can't use dynamic pointer cast at all ? Because I just can't remove the -stdc++11, it's not my project

Comment: I will try to use the shared_ptr of C++ then